# How is this integer value turned into a string in this program? (Details within)

Tags: c#

This bit of code I found from another page on Stackoverflow turns numbers into their verbal counterparts in the correct nomenclature. The code works fine but I can not work my head around why, for example if I input 1000000 (1 million)

```
if ((number / 1000000) > 0)
{
    words += NumberToWords(number / 1000000) + " Million ";
    number %= 1000000;   
}
```

Here is the part  that confuses me, it assigns the string words `[NumberToWords(number/1000000) + " Million "`. I get the million part but how does the program figure out the first part of the string is indeed "One"

Here is the full code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number to convert [Between 1 and 1 million]:");

int intUser = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("{0}", NumberToWords(intUser));
Console.ReadKey();

public static string NumberToWords(int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
       return "Zero";

    if (number < 0)
       return "Minus " + NumberToWords(Math.Abs(number));

    string words = "";

    if ((number / 1000000) > 0)
    {
        words += NumberToWords(number / 1000000) + " Million ";
        number %= 1000000;
    }

    if ((number / 1000) > 0)
    {
        words += NumberToWords(number / 1000) + " Thousand ";
        number %= 1000;
    }

    if ((number / 100) > 0)
    {
        words += NumberToWords(number / 100) + " Hundred ";
        number %= 100;
    }

    if (number > 0)
    {
        if (words != "")
            words += "and ";

        var unitsMap = new[] { "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen" };
        var tensMap = new[] { "Zero", "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety" };

        if (number < 20)
            words += unitsMap[number];
        else
        {
            words += tensMap[number / 10];

            if ((number % 10) > 0)
                words += "-" + unitsMap[number % 10];
        }
    }

    return words;
}
```

Comment: essentially, it uses recursive concept and integer division... still, the code looks pretty well-written

Comment: Could you explain this concept to me in context to this program, Im just getting into C#

Comment: Follow the code with a debugger, or just reading. Imagine `intUser` is set to `1,000,000`. The first thing it does is call `words += NumberToWords(number / 1000000) + " Million ";`. It's passing the value `1` into `NumberToWords`. Then follow that path again. This time it only enters the final `if` (`number > 0`). The number is `<20`, so `words += unitsMap[1]` (which is set to `One` right above).

Comment: That being said, since you're just getting into `C#`, this is a good opportunity to use a debugger and follow the path of code for different inputs.

Comment: The recursive concept and the integer division concepts by themselves are not hard to understand, but how these concepts are applied to the code such that the code is well-written is not as simple. To explain what is `recursive` function and integer division alone are a lot easier, but to explain the code is a bit lengthy as it is well-written. My advise is try to understand what are those two concepts and then try to use debugger to understand how the code works - applying those two concepts.

Comment: @Rob I see now! Thanks for the explanation. So it basically does the path twice in the case of '1000000' no?

Comment: Yes - in this case it will go twice. If your number was 1,100,000 it would enter three times (there's a thousands checker as well). Same goes with hundreds. The only time it would only call `NumberToWords` once would be if the value was `< 100`

Comment: @Ian I'd say the code should use a `StringBuilder` instead of concatenation.

Comment: @Rob Thankyou for the quick and simple explanation

Comment: No worries mate :)

Comment: @Jodrell regarding the efficiency, yes it is not that efficient because of the concatenation of the string. I say "well-written" in the sense that the code use recursive and integer division to produce its desired behavior pretty-well. ;)

Comment: @Jodrell Honestly though, `stringbuilder` is probably a bit of an overoptimisation (at least not something to look down upon for not using) since the maximum amount of concatenations is `16` (2,147,483,647 - two billion one hundred forty seven million four hundred eighty three thousand six hundred forty seven), and they're small strings. I would imagine the average case would be ~2-6 concatenations

Comment: @Rob I'd say, if the value is `> -20` and `< 99` Then concatenation is optimal, otherwise use a `StringBuilder`. If you don't want to check then use a `StringBuilder` as it offers better balance. Anyway, there are other performance optimizations that could be made and the code is a good muse for the OP. These performance differences would be negligible unless projecting a large set.

Answer (score 1):

It is a recursive function that calls itself for each number in the string. A single number is used as an index to retrieve the string value from the array.

i.e.

```
var unitsMap = new[] { "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen" };
```

Example - `unitMap[5]` would yield 'Five'